# jQuery Plugin not working with 1.3

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am using this time-picker plugin.

labs.perifer.se/timedatepicker/jquery.timePicker.js

It works fine with jquery 1.2. see here.

labs.perifer.se/timedatepicker/

but when used with jQuery 1.3 IE is throwing some errors.. like Error: 'jQuery' is undefined. I am using IE 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have a typo in the path your loading jQuery from.  Double check your file names, paths and compare with whats in your script tag or alternatively load jQuery directly from google:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js

Then you never have to worry about path typos or the wrong file version again.

Comment: You are correct .The path was an issue. I got confused as it was working fine in other browsers . Only IE was throwing error.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you need to make sure that your reference to jQuery comes before your reference to the timepicker.js, otherwise you will get that error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="..path to jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="..path to timepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice, didn't think of that at first.